# WebView textarea doesn't allow user to enter values

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a textarea in my webview in android. When the user clicks on the textarea the keybpard pops up but the user is not able to enter any text in it.

Here is my code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
df = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
df.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
df.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
df.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
df.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
df.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
df.requestFocus();
```

When running the same file in a desktop browser I am able to edit the contents in the textarea.

Comment: Does replacing `df.requestFocus();` with 
 `df.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` work by any chance?

Comment: @LeonLucardie no.it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue?